# Why package installation order differ was different on two machines?

Tags: apt

In Ubuntu, I run

```
apt-get install --assume-yes --force-yes packageA packageB
```

Some details:

```
packageA depends on packageC
packageB depends on packageD
```

Always, the installation order should be C->A->D->B (packageB installed after packageA installed), which I can understand.
But sometime (on another machine), the order is D->B->C->A (packageB installed before packageA installed), which I cannot understand.

**My question is why packageB installed before packageA sometimes (or on some machines).**

Anyone can explain this? Did I miss anything?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

I tried the above command on two machines. On my machine, the order is always packageB->packageA, but on the other machine, the order is always packageA->packageB, which confuses me a lot. Still stuck in this issue.
Any comments welcomed.

**Is the order to install packageA and packageB random?**

Comment: I can't understand the question.

Comment: it is still not clear. Obviously C should be installed before A, and D before B. I see nothing that can be answered. Why are you confused?

Comment: @Pilot6 My question is why packageB installed before packageA sometimes (or on some machines).

Comment: Why does it matter to you in what order they are installed, since both are installed?

Comment: @Pilot6 I just need to understand the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , always apt manages to install packages and its dependencies in a sorted manner alphabetically ascending. 

 However if two machines show different installations seems doubtful that whether you are installing same packages in both machines and both machines request same dependencies to be installed. I am afraid whether both machines have difference in installed dependencies.

Comment: But I used the same sources.list

Comment: Is the order to install packageA and packageB random?

Comment: No , while you go through the dependencies to be installed  you see while installing package A and B , its all listed in alphabetical order . So installation of packages will be in alphabetical order and dependencies as well. And always dependencies will be installed first and then the packages all in alphabetical ascending order.